# How to disable routing to destination endpoint in pre-filter using Spring Cloud Gateway framework?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Our application is built using Netflix Zuul 1.x framework and there are couple of restricted endpoints in which policies are enforced. If the user does not have sufficient privilege to access the target endpoint then the request is rejected in the filter itself and FORBIDDEN response status is returned.

The routing to destination endpoint is disabled in the filter by using setSendZuulResponse method as described in the following post:
https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/issues/543

I am looking for similar method or feature support in Spring Cloud Gateway framework.
Please share details of any such available method in Spring Cloud Gateway.